# Express router sending HTML headers instead of JSON using Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an API `router.post` that is sending the wrong headers, I need the headers to be set to `application/json; charset=utf-8` however they are sending over as `text/html; charset=utf-8` so I keep getting a `400 error`. How can I make sure they are sending over as JSON correctly so I can handle the POST and the errors necessary?

**Router**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const passport = require('passport');

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    User.register(new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email
    }),
    req.body.password, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json({
                err: err
            });
        } else {
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
                User.findOne({
                    username: req.body.username
                }, (err, person) => {
                    res.statusCode = 200;
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        status: 'Registration Successful!',
                    });
                });
            })
        }
    })
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, (err, person) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({
            success: true,
            status: 'You are successfully logged in!'
        });
    })
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session) {
        req.logout();
        req.session.destroy((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.clearCookie('session-id');
                res.json({
                    message: 'You are successfully logged out!'
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        var err = new Error('You are not logged in!');
        err.status = 403;
        next(err);
    }
});
```

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(session({
    name: '...',
    secret: '...',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Passport
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Comment: I think there must be something else wrong from what you think because your `router.post('/login', ...)` route is definitely going to be setting the content-type to `application/json`, not `text/html`.  Can you  describe how this route is being used and how you've concluded it's `text/html`?  FYI, a 400 error is not something your `router.post('/login', ...)` route is capable of sending so if you're really getting a 400 error, then it's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I'd suggest you set a breakpoint in your route and trace through it or put several `console.log()` statements in the route and track what's happening.  My guess is that the route isn't  even being hit and the error is coming from elsewhere in your server.

Comment: Which router is `router.post('/login', ...)` part of?  I'd like to see how you register that router in your `app.js` file and I'd like to know what exact url from the client you're using to access it.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your reply, I updated the full router.js; `'/signup'` and `/logout` work fine and send headers as `application/json; charset=utf-8` that's why I keep getting stuck with `/login`

Comment: Did you check to see if your code in the route is actually getting hit?  I don't think it is.  From what I see in your code, I would guess that your middleware `passport.authenticate('local', { failWithError: true })` is failing the request and perhaps because it isn't finding what it expects in the incoming request (guessing that based on the 400 status).  I don't know passport myself, but that's the next place to look.

Comment: This [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#usage) looks like the expected usage of your `passport.authenticate('local', ...)`.  This also doesn't seem right with looking up the user in your route.  You either already did that in passport or you shouldn't be using passport in this way.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for your help, I updated the `router.post('/login')` and it appears as long as I don't send over empty values the correct error is sent back. I know how to restrict empty values from sending on the frontend, now I will have to figure out how to safe check those in the `router.post` if possible

Comment: I can't tell from that comment.   Does that mean you've figured out the problem with your passport code?

Comment: @jfriend00 if `username: req.body.username` is empty then the error sent back is `Bad Request 400`

Comment: You can either add your own middleware before the passport middleware to sanity check `req.body.username` and send back your desired error or you can probably customize your local strategy to return the desired error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an API router.post that is sending the wrong headers, I need the headers to be set to application/json; charset=utf-8 however they are sending over as text/html; charset=utf-8 so I keep getting a 400 error. How can I make sure they are sending over as JSON correctly so I can handle the POST and the errors necessary?

The 400 error is apparently coming from the passport middleware:

```
passport.authenticate('local', { failWithError: true })
```

in your route definition:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
```

You will need to examine the code for your local strategy.  By definition `passport.authenticate('local')` is expecting a very specific type of incoming data.  If it doesn't find that data, it will conclude it is a bad request.

> if `req.body.username` is empty then the error sent back is Bad Request 400

You can either add your own middleware before the passport middleware to sanity check `req.body.username` and send back your desired error or you can probably customize your local strategy to return the desired error.

---

It also seems odds to me that you're looking up the user in the database in your passport local strategy and then in your route, you're looking it up again.  You should not have to do that.  You should configure and use passport to either authenticate, fail the request or pass the error to your own error handling code.  You shouldn't have to verify that passport did its job by looking up the user again.